# how do I view all of my pending changes in VSTS Source Control Explorer?

Tags: c#, tfs

I'm relatively new to TFS and perhaps because I'm a novice,
I'm not too thrilled with its behaviour.

Scenario:

I copy a source tree from the TFS server to my local hard drive.

I open a solution from my local hard drive by browsing to the .sln file.

From the vs Solution Explorer I double-click a .cs file.

Even though I'm just looking at it, that file is often marked as checked out to me.  This happens for example if I accidentally insert a blank line, even if I undo the accidental insert and even though the vs tabs imply that the .cs file is locked.

Even though I've changed nothing, Source Control Explorer acts as if there are pending changes.

I am able to right-click the file and "Undo Pending Changes...".

QUESTION:  how can I get a list or report from TFS that shows ALL of the files tagged with my Windows user id?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just right click the folder in Source Control Explorer or the solution tree...whichever you want to see under, and view pending changes.

Alternatively, if you're against a single TFS server, go to **View** -> **Other Windows** -> **Pending Changes**

Also, [Attrice TFS Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) has some handy tools for this you might want to check out.

Comment: This seems to be what I was looking for in that it lists my own pending changes.

Answer (score 2):

Menu: View -> Other Windows -> Pending Changes

If you open more than one VS instance, the window content might be out-dated, so hit "Refresh" button on top of Pending Changes tool window to be sure.

You may also want VS to prompt you upon check-out, to make your life easier.
Go to Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Environment -> Checked-in items
and change the values to "Prompt for Checkout"

Comment: thank you ... Nick Craver answered this first ... it seems that stackoverflow will not let me mark this also as the correct answer. at forums.asp.net I could mark both.  I'm still new to stackoverflow and am still trying to figure out how stackoverflow works.  For me, it's still a confusing paradigm.